# Can't dump mysql backup file

Tags: backup, mysql

I have created a backup of my database and now I want to dump it in to my local machine. My machine is linux machine and I have th eroot password for machine. I tried to dump the in to my local backup database using root password on ssh, but i keep getting an errror . "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)". Please suggest me what to do

This is the command I am using " mysql  < backup.dump.gz"

Comment: Specify a password using the `-p` switch.

Comment: Are you using the `-p` option on your `mysqldump` command line? The error message would suggest you are not.

Comment: @pekka Two seconds ahead of me :)

Comment: Can you post the command line you are using (replacing the pasword with "password" of course"

Comment: find out what the mysql root password is -- it's different from the system account.

Comment: This is the command I am using " mysql < backup.dump.gz"

Comment: I am very new to mysql, Please tell me what the command would be ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming; it belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Apart from the password problem, I don't think `mysql` can take a compressed file on stdin, you need to uncompress it first, or pipe it in from `zcat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

gunzip < backup.dump.gz | mysql -u root -p

And enter your password when prompted.

Comment: Still gives me the same error !